# Popup visual decoration

Tags: android, popup

I need to implement user popup dialogs, but they don't look like standard. I guess, there's a way of implementing custom popups by means of Android's functionality (custom dialogs), but is it possible to decorate them ? 
Yet it might not be  the best solution for this problem - should I try something else like hidden layouts ?

Thank you.

Comment: there are plenty of links in the Google for creating custom dialogs..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can change your Dialog box as you want.You can do this by creating a custom dialog box. 
Step1. Create a style in String file in res

```
 <style name="myQuitDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog"> 
   <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>

    </style>
```

Step2. Create the xml file in layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_quit"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/image which u want to show"
 >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Step3. Write code of custom dialog box in src

```
class Custom_Dialog extends Dialog {

    protected Custom_Dialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private void show_alert() {
        final Custom_Dialog alertbox = new Custom_Dialog(this, R.style.myQuitDialog);
        Window window = alertbox.getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        window.requestFeature(window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        alertbox.show(); 
        alertbox.setCancelable(true);
        alertbox.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        alertbox.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably what I want, but are there any drawbacks with this method ? Does anyone implement pseudo-popups using layouts ?

Comment: yes u can implement it and there is no drawback.If u feel my answer is right then plz don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear to me because you dont specify weather you want to customize and use the alert dialog or pop up dialog.In android both are different.In android pop up dialog named quick actions.I am posting below a link that will give you brief idea about quick action and explain brilliantly how to implement it in ur app.So go for it.

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: I got you -I've never seen quick action before. I'm going for a custom dialog, but thanks for the link - it's going to have another useful application.